# how can I find the number of instances a value occur in different columns in an R dataset?

Tags: r, dataset

This is a reproducible example of a dataset I have:

```
Health <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),
                     ethnicity = c(2,2,2,1,1),
                     dead=c(0,0,0,0,1), 
                     Asthma = c(1,1,1,0,0),
                     Diabetes = c(1,0,1,0,1),
                     Sex = c("M","F","M","M","M"))
```

I would like to know how I can calculate the number of instances each value occurs in the dataset which I would then export as a separate table.

My expected results look like this:

```
          0  1  2
Ethnicity    3  2
Asthma    2  3
Dead      4  1
Diabetes  2  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: this is similar to Sotos answer.

You can use `table()` after you `gather` in long format:

```
library(dplyr)

Health %>% 
    select(-id, -Sex) %>% 
    tidyr::gather("key", "value") %>% 
    group_by(key) %>% 
    table()

#            value
#key         0 1 2
#  Asthma    2 3 0
#  dead      4 1 0
#  Diabetes  2 3 0
#  ethnicity 0 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert to long format first, count and spread, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

Health %>% 
 gather(var, val, -c(id, Sex)) %>% 
 group_by(var, val) %>% 
 count() %>% 
 spread(val, n, fill = 0)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 4
> # Groups:   var [4]
>    var         `0`   `1`   `2`
>   <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
> 1 Asthma        2     3     0
> 2 dead          4     1     0
> 3 Diabetes      2     3     0 
> 4 ethnicity     0     2     3
> ```

A base R solution of this concept can be (compliments of @markus),

```
t(table(stack(Health[, 2:5])))
#           values
#ind         0 1 2
#  ethnicity 0 2 3
#  dead      4 1 0
#  Asthma    2 3 0
#  Diabetes  2 3 0
```